# isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) always returns false in android 2.3

Tags: android, gps, location

I am trying to redirect the user to **Location Settings Screen** using an

Alert Dialog to so that he can enable the GPS, But after I enable

the **Use Wireless Network** checkbox on Api 2.3 and return to previous Activity

its again showing me the Alert Dialog for settings screen.

because this line :

```
isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

**is always returning false.**

I am using below code to redirect to **Locations Setting.**

```
Intent im=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
startActivity(im);
```

**But on Api 5.1.1 the same code is working fine and returning true**

Why is it so ?

Thanks In Advance...

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: yes actually the problem was that i was having an older device with version 2.3 and  it was not having GPS ? So silly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the device with version 2.3 that I was using for testing was not having GPS so I was always getting the value false and I figured it out when I accidently read my phone's specification